# paperjs: clip two paths

Tags: javascript, clipping, polygons, paperjs

Im trying to exclude 1 polygon from another polygon in paperjs, but cant seem to figure out how to do this.

```
var base_points = [[50,50],[100,50],[125,10]];
var clipPolygon = [[50, 50], [100,50], [100,0], [200, 0],[200,300]];

var base = PointsToPath(base_points);
base.strokeColor = "#000";

var clip =   PointsToPath(clipPolygon);
clip.strokeColor = "#ff00";

var clipped = base.exclude(clip)
clipped.fillColor = '#00ff00'
```

I made a jsfiddle attempting to do this here.

http://jsfiddle.net/thesamprice/9jm896gd/6/

It seems like the paperjs manual says this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

jsfiddle seems to have been using an older paperjs link, the code was working as expected.

[paperjs sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of the boolean operations that Paper.js allows:

```
unite(path[, options])
intersect(path[, options])
subtract(path[, options])
exclude(path[, options])
divide(path[, options])
reorient([nonZero[, clockwise]])
```

[here is the link to some](http://paperjs.org/reference/pathitem/#intersect-path)